# show structure of all levels of json with jq and bash

Tags: json, bash, structure, jq, datamodel

How can I list all unique keys of a json file for all levels and array attributes, together with their path?

I found jq -s 'map(keys) | add | unique | sort' input.json, but this only lists the first level, and no paths.

Comment: you could provide a sample json file.

Answer (score 3):

If you stream the input in, it will give you pairs of the paths and values contained in the input.

```
$ jq --stream 'select(length>1)[0]' input.json
```

So for an input like this:

```
{
  "foo": { "bar": 1 },
  "biz": { "baz": 2 }
}
```

You'd get:

```
[
  "foo",
  "bar"
]
[
  "biz",
  "baz"
]
```